# ZigBee on a microcontroller

Tags: networking, zigbee

I am not familiar with [ZigBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee) technology. And I am bit confused. Does Zigbee need a transmitter and receiver? How is its networking flow?

I was thinking of the notifications that our system have would be send to an application in a PC via ZigBee. That is, drop rate changes of [dextrose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucose) shows in an application / interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZigBee is built on top of the 802.15.4 standard. It's a bi-directional protocol... so to participate in a ZigBee network (or any 802.15.4 network) you need a transceiver (transmitter+receiver). There are lots of products on the market, but I'd suggest you take a look at the Digi XBee modules. A lot of the complexity of implementing ZigBee is built into the modules so that you don't have to worry about it.

The book "Building Wireless Sensor Networks" by O'Reilly is a good start if you go the XBee route.